# pass string to emailbody (iphone)

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

hopefully a simple question for anyone who knows what they are doing...

I have a string variable with user input text.

I then bring up a email view based on Apples example MailComposerViewController and I want the text to populate the body of the email.

In as simple as possible terms how do I get the string variable into emailBody?

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet 
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

```
[picker setSubject:@"Subject Line"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"marko@test.com"]; 

[picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];


// Fill out the email body text
NSString *emailBody = @"Replace with string plz";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}

---

**Update**:

project is openFrameworks based

& hassle stems I presume from mix of c++ & objective c

mainApp.h contains

```
class mainApp: public ofxiPhoneApp {
public:
    string mainText;
    // edit
};
```

mainApp.mm contains

```
void mainApp::draw() {
    // edit
    mainText = keyboard->getText();
    // edit
}
```

& it all runs ok on hardware but I'm completely lost on sorting this

---

**Update 2**:

still cant figure how to make 'accessor (getter) method'

while I can now convert the user input string to NSString

the bit I cant do is figure how to pass that to the code in the MainComposerViewController file without it crashing

```
NSString * fred = myApp->mainText;
```

??

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I am also a newbie and had quite a great deal of trouble with this, this tutorial explaied it really well...
[iPhone Tutorial: Elegant way to send formatted In-App email](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-elegant-way-to-send-formatted-in-app-email/)